# How to serialize a libtorch vector of tuple(std::string, torch::Tensor) using protobuf?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, tensor, libtorch

How should I define the ProtoBuf schema so that I can serialize this vector of shape?

```
std::vector<std::tuple(std::string, torch::Tensor)>
```

All I could find were simple trivial examples. I have no idea how I should be defining the `torch::Tensor` or the `tuple` in the ProtoBuf schema!

Comment: Look at this thread: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19025#issuecomment-482308272. A solution could be to convert to `std::string` using `std::stringstream` (`torch::save()`), serialize it as a string and then load back from it and convert back to `torch::Tensor` (`torch::load()`).

Comment: @Azeem thanks a lot. but I need to serialize them as a tuple and not alone!

Comment: Well, in ProroBuf, you'd be combining them together as a message, right? Please update your question with your `.proto` definition as well that would help understand how you're visualizing it.

Comment: @Azeem, I dont have any .proto file implemented yet, as I'm yet to find out how I should be going about this, what should I be defining and how. for example should the tuple be ```message { string key =1; Tensor embd =2}``` this looks not right to me, so I asked how I should be going about this. protobuf clearly supports strings, so if I'm not mistaken, I dont have to change the string part, the main issue seems to be the Tensor itself and how it should be defined in the message. please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: That `key` in the message seems like you need a [`map`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#maps). Example: `map<string, string> lookup = 1;` where key is string and value `torch::Tensor` is also a string generated by `torch::save()`.

Comment: @Azeem, Now I'm getting it, thanks, then there is no need to define Tensor at all, simply the string representation of it that has been already serialized by torch itself can be used. this is great . by the way, the keys are the same, so is this map, the c++ map or specific to protobuf? as if I recall correctly, stdl map had unique keys (in my case maybe multimap would work as keys are not unique!))

Comment: Right. You can just use the string representation of `torch::Tensor`. The `map` is similar to `std::unordered_map`. It's a custom implementation. See its APIs [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.map). For duplicated keys, you may use something like this: https://godbolt.org/z/qqd6d5.

Comment: @Azeem Thanks a lot really appreciate it. Please kindly post this as the answer so we can call this question a day! I'll comment under it in case I faced any thing.

Comment: Sure. You're welcome! :) Good luck with the rest of serialization/deserialization! I hope it would be a piece of cake now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string` to represent `torch::Tensor` in the ProtoBuf schema.

Example:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package tensor;

message Lookup {
    message Tuple {
        string key = 1;
        string tensor = 2;
    }

    repeated Tuple tuples = 1;
}
```

Use `torch::save()` and `torch::load()` APIs to convert to/from `std::string` via `std::stringstream` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/19025#issuecomment-482308272).

Comment: Hi, How should I be adding to Lookup? it seems it doesnt hanve any set or add method!

Comment: the only add method it offers, doesnt take any arguments! and its `add_tuples`!

Comment: OK got it. I first had to create a new Tuple object from tuples and then update the Tuple!:
```tensor::Tuple vec;
   auto record = vec.add_tuples();
   record.set_key("key");
   record.set_tensor("tensor");```
and this way, the vec is filled up! pretty un-intuitive if you ask me!

Comment: @Rika: Hi. Yup, at first, it's like that. You might want to look at the relevant APIs of the `repeated` field, see [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#repeatedmessage). The method `add_tupes()` would return a pointer to the newly added element so it would be `record->set_key("key");` and `record->set_tensor("tensor");`.

Comment: yes I already fixed that, thanks a lot for the generous help really appreciate it brother ;)

Comment: @Rika: Awesome! My pleasure! :)